# Search inside of a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, substring

I have a string that I want to parse using javascript. The string contents are

> Tue Apr 02 2013 13:36:56 GMT -0500 (Central Daylight Time)

I need to get javascript to "get the word after open parenthesis" (in this case "Central").

I can't seem to figure out the javascript code for that. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:asp.net]?

Comment: Try a regex maybe? Or use something like `str.split("(")[1].split(/\s/)[0]`

Comment: Use [javascript string manipulation functions](http://www.jquery4u.com/javascript/15-javascript-string-functions/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a regex, you could use this:

```
var re = /\(([A-Za-z0-9]+)[ )]/;
var str = "Tue Apr 02 2013 13:36:56 GMT -0500 (Central Daylight Time)";
var matching = str.match(re);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/BzxtY/

Since you want the specific word, you'd use `matching[1]` to get the specific word matched. Of course, the match *could* be `null`, so you might want to check that first. If you're sure this regex will match, don't bother :)

To break it down:

- `\(` - Starts with `(`
- `(` - (beginning of matching group)
- `[A-Za-z0-9]+` - Contains any at least one of A-Z, a-z, 0-9
- `)` - (end of matching group)
- `[ )]` - Ends with a  (space) or `)`

The final part should match a single word in the `()` or multiple words (and only get the first, as you want). Such as matching "Central" in "(Central Daylight Time)" or matching "Testing" in "(Testing)".

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
var xStr="Tue Apr 02 2013 13:36:56 GMT -0500 (Central Daylight Time)"
alert(xStr.substring(xStr.indexOf("(")+1).split(" ")[0]);
```

[Concepts used: [**substring**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring), [**indexOf**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), [**split**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)]

Answer (score 1):

Use indexOf() to get the index of the first paren. Once you have that then get all of the characters up to the next space.

```
var str = "Tue Apr 02 2013 13:36:56 GMT -0500 (Central Daylight Time)";

var parenIdx = str.indexOf('(') + 1;
var result = str.substring(parenIdx, str.indexOf(' ', parenIdx));
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree - regex is the way (especially were it to be elegant):

```
<string>.replace(/.*\(([^\s]*)\s.*/,'$1');
```

(n.b. There *will* be more elegant regex for this)

Cheers.